# Sending Email Messages exposes the email addresses of every user to the recipients. How to fix?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I like to send mails such that my JobNotifier/Mailer iterates through the Subscriber's Email List and call deliver "n" times, if that could be the solution to my problem.

Unfortunately, all I have done sends Emails Messages and expose the email addresses of every user to the recipients, which is not suppose to be.

Here are my codes

**create method right inside my jobs_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)
    if @job.save
      # Deliver the Posted Job
      JobNotifier.send_post_email(@job).deliver
      redirect_to preview_job_path(@job)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

**app/mailers/application_mailer.rb**

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
   default to: Proc.new { User.pluck(:email).uniq },
           from: 'FarFlungJobs <no-reply@farflungjobs.com>'

   layout 'mailer'

end
```

**app/mailers/job_notifier.rb**

```
class JobNotifier < ApplicationMailer

  def send_post_email(job)
    @jobs = job
    mail( :subject => 'New job posted on FarFlungJobs'
        )
  end

end
```

**test/mailers/preview/job_notifier_preview.rb**

```
# Preview all emails at http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/job_notifier
class JobNotifierPreview < ActionMailer::Preview

  def send_post_email
    user = User.all
    JobNotifier.send_post_email(user)
  end

end
```

Tried to hop on my browser to test my Mailer using the URL shown below to preview/test my mailer:

> http://localhost:3000/rails/mailers/job_notifier/send_post_email

Outcome of my test is this image below (at least if needed to help me with my problem):

[image: Test View]

Am using Rails 
4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the email to each user separately. It will take much longer but it won't show other user's emails.

So in your controller, you will have something like this:

```
def create
  @job = Job.new(job_params)
  if @job.save

    User.pluck(:email).uniq.each do |email|
      # Deliver the Posted Job
      JobNotifier.send_post_email(@job, email).deliver
    end

    redirect_to preview_job_path(@job)
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Or you could put the loop inside the mailer

Edit:

You'll need to change your mailer to be able to handle extra argument:

```
class JobNotifier < ApplicationMailer

  def send_post_email(job, email)
    @jobs = job
    mail(:to => email :subject => 'New job posted on FarFlungJobs')
  end

end
```

Comment: I get an error doing this. The error is "wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)". I suppose the block is the one throwing an error.

Comment: Even when I move it to the Mailer, I still get the same error. wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Comment: Quite unfortunate, that doesn't fix it. The same error persists. @Ruslan

Comment: @AfolabiOlaoluwaAkinwumi what's the full exception?

Comment: It is giving me so much problem, and I have used `:bcc` instead, and that worked. But that leaves me with a problem: 
When a mail is sent, on the `:to` attribute, it shows no email address, but shows `Unspecified` instead.

Comment: and this is what I changed my Mailer to:


`class JobNotifier < ApplicationMailer

  def send_post_email(job)
    @user = User.where(:email => true).all
    emails = @user.collect(&:email).join(',')
    @jobs = job
      mail(:to => emails,:bcc => User.pluck(:email).uniq, :subject => 'New job posted on FarFlungJobs')
  end
end`